# Create a URL in a template using RazorEngine

Tags: asp.net, razorengine

Useing the RazorEngine library from here - http://razorengine.codeplex.com/.
I'm trying to create a URL with parameters where the parameters value comes from the @Model.
This is the HTML I use for the URL:

```
<p>http://@Model.WebsiteURL/login.aspx?bookingid=@model.BookingID&user=@Model.EmailParent&password=@Model.Password&ReturnUrl=betaling.aspx</p>
```

But when the Razor engine try to parse the template I get this error:
"Only one 'model' statement is allowed in a file."
Do I remove the @model.??? so that it only is used ones it is OK.

How do I create this URL.

Thanks in advance

Anders Pedersen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p>http://@Model.WebsiteURL/login.aspx?bookingid=@model.BookingID&user=@Model.EmailParent&password=@Model.Password&ReturnUrl=betaling.aspx</p>
```

Notice the small "m" in the "@model.BookingID"... it needs to be a capital M.

Comment: Holy "sh**" that I could miss that one. I guess that I was to busy finding a solution in formatting a Html link .
Thanks  a lot :-)

Comment: Happens to all of us, glad I could help you out :)